# inline conditional statement in jsrender

Tags: jsrender

Just a quick one, cant seem to figure out why this doesn't work:

```
list :  '<div id="{{>id}}" class="gridRow cf">' +
    '   <div class="threeCol"><img src="{{>image}}" /></div>' +
    '   <div class="threeCol">{{>name}}</div>' +
    '   <div class="sixCol last">' +
    '       <div class="button cupid-green" {{if buttonAction}} data-action="{{>buttonAction"}} {{/if}} {{if gameId}} data-game-id="{{>gameId}}" {{/if}}>{{>buttonText}}</div>' +
    '   </div>' + 
    '</div>'
```

I get an error along the lines of

```
04-15 22:46:56.960: E/Web Console(20319): Uncaught JsRender Error: Syntax error
04-15 22:46:56.960: E/Web Console(20319): Compiled template code:
04-15 22:46:56.960: E/Web Console(20319): // list/if
04-15 22:46:56.960: E/Web Console(20319): var j=j||jQuery.views,h=j.converters.html,ret="";
04-15 22:46:56.960: E/Web Console(20319): try{
04-15 22:46:56.960: E/Web Console(20319): ret+=" data-action=\"";
04-15 22:46:56.960: E/Web Console(20319): ret+=h(data.buttonAction");
04-15 22:46:56.960: E/Web Console(20319): ret+=" ";
04-15 22:46:56.960: E/Web Console(20319): return ret;
04-15 22:46:56.960: E/Web Console(20319): }catch(e){return j._err(e);}:854
```

anyone know what causes this?

regards

Comment: I think the problem is hidden here:

data-action="{{>buttonAction"}}

Comment: Typo:  `data-action="{{>buttonAction"}}` should be `data-action="{{>buttonAction}}"`  The syntax error before your `if` causes the parser to choke and never gets to it.